# Transform list in a JSON, then adding an header on top of this JSON

Tags: java, json, list, nodes

I have a list of objects:

```
List<ScuolaEntity> result = scuolaService.getAllScuoleEntity();
```

I would like to convert the list in a json object, I have tried with gson, with JSONObject and even with JsonNode, but I couldn't find a way to add a header/node to the json.

This is the actual json:

```
[
    {
        "codiceMeccanografico": "RMAT123456",
        "codiceFiscale": "CREMHL90T42B745CQQE",
        "denominazione": "ITS INCOM"
    },
    {
        "codiceMeccanografico": "RMAT891011",
        "codiceFiscale": "SCEMQL90T42B735CWQ1",
        "denominazione": "Liceo Scientifico Statale E. Lussu"
    }
]
```

This is what I would like to achieve

```
{
  "scuole": [
    {
        "codiceMeccanografico": "RMAT123456",
        "codiceFiscale": "CREMHL90T42B745CQQE",
        "denominazione": "ITS INCOM"
    },
    {
        "codiceMeccanografico": "RMAT891011",
        "codiceFiscale": "SCEMQL90T42B735CWQ1",
        "denominazione": "Liceo Scientifico Statale E. Lussu"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can I add this header "scuole" with gson library or another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this by wrapping this list into a map:

```java
List<ScuolaEntity> result = scuolaService.getAllScuoleEntity();
Map data=Collections.singletoneMap("scuole",result);
```

And then encode this map as JSON.

Comment: Hello Mungai, thank you for your answer. Do you know if with the way you showed it's even possible to add nested headers?

Comment: Yes, you need to add a key to a map each time you need to add a header. JSON is a map-like/based structure in Java.